# How To Delete Multiple Data From Different Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables like this

**Books**
`id|book_name|writter_id`
`1|Artemis|1`

---

**Writters**
`id|writter_name`
`1|Jane Doe`

---

both of the tables have a relationship like this

**Book model** `return $this->belongsTo('App\Writter', 'writter_id');`
**Writter model** `return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'writter_id');`

`books.index.blade.php`

```
<p>{{ $book->writter->writter_name }}</p>
```

**create books**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('book_name', 100)->unique();
        $table->integer('writter_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

create writter

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('writters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('writter_name', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Set Foreign Key 
        Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('writter_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('writers')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // Drop Foreign Key di kolom id_penulis di table books
        Schema::table('books', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('books_writter_id_foreign');
        }); 

        Schema::drop('writters');
    }
```

Every time i delete the writters (for an example like jane doe above) the books data still have the `writter_id` So the index view throw me an error.

Is it possible to delete the data/row from the **writters** table, and delete the `writter_id` on the **books** in the same time?

Comment: You should have set up foreign keys on your mysql table. Show us how your tables look like with `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`.

Comment: @Marwelln: how did you find out the OP is using mysql?

Comment: @Marwelln do you have any refference? i'm really newbie on mysql and laravel

Comment: search for MySQL and  "referential integrity"

Comment: @Marwelln kindly check the update

Answer (score 0):

Edit your books table migration and add foreign keys

```
$table->integer('writter_id')->unsigned()->nullable();


Schema::table('books', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('writter_id')->references('id')->on('writters')->onDelete('set null');
});
```

As you see it sets null on writter delete

Answer (score 0):

For make youre migration file, do you use foreign key ? 
With foreign key you can add a method for on Delete.

[Foreign key Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

**migration.php**

```
$table->integer('writter_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('writter_id)->references('id')->on('writters)->onDelete('cascade');
```

It's will be work

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't set up foreign keys on your tables, removing a row from a table won't update the column referencing to that row.

To solve this we can set up [foreign keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) with the schema builder.

You can create a new migration file or modify your existing migrations if you don't care about your current database values.

Create a new migration file with `php artisan make:migration`. Inside that file, use these methods (don't forget to run `composer require doctrine/dbal` before running the migration):

```
public function up() {
    // Remove current foreign keys and index.
    Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('books_writter_id_foreign');
        $table->dropIndex('books_writter_id_foreign');
    });

    // Add new foreign and allow books to now have a writter by using `NULL`.
    Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('writter_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->change(); // Before changing a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your  composer.json file.

        $table->foreign('writter_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('writers')
                ->onDelete('SET NULL');
    });
}

public function down() {
    // Revert to previous values.
    Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('books_writter_id_foreign');
        $table->dropIndex('books_writter_id_foreign');

        $table->integer('writter_id')->unsigned()->change();

        $table->foreign('writter_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('writers')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

Using `->onDelete('SET NULL')` on the foreign key will set the value to `NULL` when the referenced value is deleted from the referenced table.

In your blade file you can now check if the book have a writer before outputting it:

```
@if ($book->writter_id)
<p>{{ $book->writter->writter_name }}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: is this to update the previous migration?  which one should i choose when make the migration is it --create or --table? and how to migrate? php artisan migrate like usual?